# Basic UI-Routing Example but an error occurs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to learn AngularJS. At the moment I focus on ui-Routing.
My Code is very simple, but it doenst work and I don't know why.

Description of my problem:

http://de.tinypic.com?ref=kd22ow.jpg

The browser shows:
"Hello World ui-Routing!" (h1 in index.html)

If I try to enter index.html/home.
It says: Error File not found!

Here is my Code:

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
        <title>My Angular App!</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="Test" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1>Hello World ui-Routing!</h1>
        <div ui-view>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('Test', ['ui-router'])

.config([
'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterprovider)
{
  $stateProvider

    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: '/home.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    });

    .state('test', {
      url: '/test',
      templateUrl: '/test.html',
      controller: 'TestCtrl'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}])

.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
function($scope){
 $scope.test = "Hello Jan!";
});

.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', 
function($scope){
 $scope.test = "Hello Redirect!";
});
```

test.html:

```
<h2>Hello Test! </h2>
```

home.html:

```
<h2>Hello Home! </h2>
```

Where is my problem?

Looking forward to your answers,
Jan

Comment: How static files are managed?

Comment: All Files are in the same folder.

Comment: Probably, you have to install server. For example: npm install static-server ; static-server

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the ui-router script in your html page too it is a third party and not included in angular.

Comment: <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

I have added this expression. But it doenst work either. Same error.
Every file (index.html, home.html, test.html and app.js) are in the same folder. Here is a picture <a href="http://de.tinypic.com?ref=kd22ow" target="_blank"><img src="http://i61.tinypic.com/kd22ow.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"></a>

Comment: Are you running the files from a webserver or directly from the harddrive? If the later, that is your problem, you will need a webserver since chrome have restrictions when loading files from disc. You can bypass these restrictions by following this guide http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/

Comment: Thanks your answer was the solution.